System.TypeLoadException for calling C# in Python
I would like to make my existing code usable in Python, but I am facing a problem. From what I understand, Visual Studio does not include all dependencies when creating the DLL during publishing. I have simplified and focused on the key areas of the issue.
Here the following C# classes:
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
public class Polygon
{
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}

public class PolygonProcessor
{
    public List<Polygon> ProcessPolygons(List<Polygon> polygons)
    {
        var vector = Vector<Vector2>.Count; //This line was added to use Numerics library

        //Some execution for the points
        var result = new List<Polygon>();
        foreach (var polygon in polygons)
        {
            var newPoly = new Polygon();
            newPoly.Points = new List<Point>();
            foreach (var point in polygon.Points)
            {
                var newPoint = new Point();
                newPoint.X = point.X + 1;
                newPoint.Y = point.Y + 1;
                newPoly.Points.Add(newPoint);
            }
            result.Add(newPoly);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

I published it as a DLL and wanted to call it from the following Python code:
import clr
clr.AddReference("DLLs/MyDllsName")

from System import Double
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from MyNameSpace import Point, Polygon, PolygonProcessor

def create_polygon(points):
    polygon = Polygon()
    polygon.Points = List[Point]()
    for x, y in points:
        point = Point()
        point.X = x
        point.Y = y
        polygon.Points.Add(point)
    return polygon



pp = PolygonProcessor()
polygons = List[Polygon]()
polygons.Add(create_polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]))
polygons.Add(create_polygon([(2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3)]))

result = pp.ProcessPolygons(polygons)

And my Error is the following:
der Assembly "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" konnte nicht geladen werden.
